# Schedule data transfer service in MySQL

Tags: data-migration, mysql

I have two DB servers, i.e Server1 and Server2.
I want to transfer data from Server1 to Server2 every morning (at 9:00AM lets say).

How can we achieve it?
Can this transfer of data be done automatically?

Comment: are you using a windows based server or linux?

Comment: I am using Windows based server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My choice on a windows machine is to create a batch file that runs `mysqldump` with the parameters that suite you best.

This batch file can be tied to the windows scheduler for an automated execution at any point in time.

you can consult [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/copying-databases.html) page for some guideline by the MySQL community.

Now that you have a dump of your DB your script should send it to the destination server and deploy it locally (can also be done automatically).

- i use the parameters for `mysqldump` that allows me to incrementally add data to the new server
- i transfer the dump using [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) which is a community windows wrapper around the rsync program (if interested you should check Syncrify on that page as well)

both of those last point allow for an extremely faster process than copying the entire DB everytime.

Comment: can mysqldump be done for a particular table or group of tables?

Comment: @Deviprasad Das : yes - check out this [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_tables) for all the parameters available as well